# Do you need spies to test if a function has been called in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

Am learning Jasmine, wondering if the following test would be valid? And if not, can someone explain why? I've been reading a number of tutorials and can't find a good explanation that has helped me understand why I can't seem to write a test like the one below correctly.

```
// spec
describe("when cart is clicked", function() {
    it("should call the populateNotes function", function() {
        $("#show-cart").click()
        expect(populateNotes()).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
})

// code
$("#show-cart").click(function() {
    populateNotes();
})
```

Comment: `expect(populateNotes())` calls the function, it should be `expect(populateNotes)`

Comment: @4castle I don't think it's a duplicate, they're missing some other bits of jasmine as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do two things, first you need to spy on the function before the click. Normally you would spy on a function like this that is a member of an object. Where is populateNotes defined? You need a reference to it somehow.

```
// This might work, if the function is defined globally. 
spyOn(window, 'populateNotes');

// Then do your action that should result in that func being called
$("#show-cart").click();

// Then your expectation. The expectation should be on the function
// itself, not on the result. So no parens.
expect(window.populateNotes).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: hmm... that didn't work, is it possible that the object isn't `window`? I literally have the function just sitting there... so window should be right...

Comment: You could define the function on window, just to make it testable. Instead of `function populateNotes(...` you can do `window.populateNotes = function(...`

Comment: so explicitly defining the function on window still didn't cause the test to pass. however i can definitely verify that it's passing in a local server... any other ideas?

Comment: What's the failure message you're getting from jasmine exactly?

Comment: `Error: Expected spy populatePreOrderNotes to have been called.`

Comment: @james Do you have screen hero? This would be a lot easier to debug if we could pair. (I work for the company that wrote jasmine)