# Angular 9 Unit Test: how to mock import of tested component?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

So I'm currently writing a Jasmine/Karma Unit Test for an Angular 9 Component.

A short summary how my application works:
I've written a little `Funnel` with D3 that displays given data in a funnel-like diagram. Then I've written a `FunnelComponent` that contains this `Funnel` and also displays some meta information next to the actual diagram.

This is my to be tested Component:

**funnel.component.ts**

```angular
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Funnel } from './d3charts/funnel.ts';
import { FunnelData } from './funnel.data';

@Component({
  selector: 'v7-funnel-component',
  templateUrl: './funnel.html'
})
export class FunnelComponent {

  private funnel: Funnel = null;

  constructor() {}

  public createFunnel(funnelData: FunnelData): void {
      this.funnel = new Funnel();
      this.funnel.setData(funnelData);
      this.funnel.draw();
  }
}
```

And here is my karma-jasmine unit-test for that Component:

**funnel.component.spec.ts**

```jasmine
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { } from 'jasmine';
import { FunnelComponent } from './funnel.component';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FunnelData } from './funnel.data';
import { Funnel } from './d3charts/funnel.ts';

@Component({selector: 'funnel', template: ''})
class FunnelStub {
  private data: FunnelData = null;

  public setData(data: FunnelData): void
  {this.data = data;}
  {}
  public draw(): void
  {}
  public update(funnelData: FunnelData): void
  {}
}

/**
 * Testing class for FunnelComponent.
 */
describe('Component: Funnel', () => {

  let component: FunnelComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FunnelComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed
    .configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        FunnelComponent,
        FunnelStub
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: Funnel, useValue: FunnelStub}
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents()
    .then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FunnelComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });
  }));

it('#createFunnel should set data of funnel. Filled data should set filled funnel.', () => {
    expect(component["funnel"]).toBeNull();

    let exampleFunnelData = new FunnelData("testcaption", "testdescription", 8);
    component.createFunnel(exampleFunnelData);

    expect(component["funnel"]).toBeDefined();
    expect(component["funnel"]["data"]).toBeDefined();
    expect(component.data.caption).toEqual("testcaption");
    expect(component.data.description).toEqual("testsubtext");
    expect(component.data.value).toEqual(8);
  });
});
```

I want to test the `createFunnel` method here.
But I don't want that my createFunnel method assigns a real `Funnel` to `this.funnel`, but uses my `FunnelStub` instead.
Any idea how to do this?

Adding `{ provide: Funnel, useValue: FunnelStub}` to my providers array didn't help :(

Best regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work, because Funnel is not a provider:

```
providers: [
  { provide: Funnel, useValue: FunnelStub}
]
```

What would help you the most for testing, would be to create a service for the Funnel creation.

```
export abstract class FunnelProvider {
  abstract createFunnel(): Funnel;
}
```

This service can then have 2 implementations, one implementation you use in your app and one that you use in your tests.

```
@Injectable()
export class DefaultFunnelProvider {
  createFunnel() {
    return new Funnel(); // Return real funnel object.
  }
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class MockFunnelProvider {
  createFunnel() {
     // Return stub funnel. Assuming that they share the same interface.
    return new FunnelStub() as Funnel;
  }
}
```

Now you have to define the `DefaultFunnelProvider` in your FunnelModule (the module that declares your FunnelComponent):

```
@NgModule({
  ... // other stuff
  providers: [{provide: FunnelProvider, useClass: DefaultFunnelProvider}]
})
export class FunnelModule {}
```

Then you inject the FunnelProvider in your FunnelComponent and use it to create the funnel:

```
export class FunnelComponent {

  private funnel: Funnel = null;

  constructor(private funnelProvider: FunnelProvider) {}

  public createFunnel(funnelData: FunnelData): void {
      this.funnel = this.funnelProvider.createFunnel();
      this.funnel.setData(funnelData);
      this.funnel.draw();
  }
}
```

A lot of work, but now the cool thing is that you can inject the Mock implementation of the FunnelProvider in your TestBed:

```
TestBed
    .configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        FunnelComponent,
        FunnelStub
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: FunnelProvider, useValue: MockFunnelProvider }
      ]
    })
```

Now when funnelProvider.createFunnel is called, it will not return a real funnel, but your funnel stub.

If you must during your test, you can cast the components funnel field to FunnelStub (e.g. if it has some special method):

```
const funnelStub = component.funnel as FunnelStub;
```

Comment: Your suggested answer is probably a solution to my problem. However, I would prefer not editing my `FunnelComponent` just to make the unit test work. I was hoping there is some TestBed Karma/Jasmine-ish way to tell the TestBed that I want to use another import for a Component created with `TestBed.createComponent`.

Comment: @Bishares : The suggested answer is not to make just the unit test work. Its about using dependency injection and delegating the task to a service so that they both (component & service) can be tested  separately.  This way you can isolate the dependency of component and replace with Mock.  https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49

Comment: @ShashankVivek convinced me. My Component should only contain template/gui logic, everything else can be delegated to a service. My inner funnel creation can therefore be encapsulated into a service.

Comment: @Bishares : Glad to help you. Cheers !